# Duplicated resources for the same film in the Linked Movie Database

Tags: linked-data

I'm using data exposed by http://www.linkedmdb.org/, from their SPARQL endpoint and I noticed that for some films, there are two resources for example:

For the film *Tales of Terror* there are this two resources:

- http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/film/34038
- http://data.linkedmdb.org/page/film/8359

For the film *The Corruptor*:

- http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/film/34739
- http://data.linkedmdb.org/page/film/18849

What are the difference between the two resources representing the same film?

Comment: All these entities are not of `rdf:type` `movie:film` (cf. http://data.linkedmdb.org/page/film/44495). Probably these entities are (side-) results of their interlinking attempts.

Comment: Side note: Are you aware that you are linking once to the resource (i.e., the film) and once to the page (i.e., the page about the film)? Doesn’t seem to be related to your question, though. -- I think it would be better to make these `/resource/` links in all cases.